# Website display issue in Firefox, all align to the right, other browsers look fine

Tags: html, css, firefox

Can anyone help to check on this site?

http://chanbaneng.com/demo/

When in Firefox, all the content gets pushed to the right. In all the other browsers I tried (Chrome, Safari, and IE), it works just fine.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Is this your own site, or someone else's?

Comment: Hi evamvid, this site is mine, haven't publish it due to the firefox problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Used to this way**

```
ul.bjqs{
overflow: hidden;  // remove this line in your css 
}
```

## ==========================

**your second problem solution is this 
now define this css in your style sheet**

```
 #container{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Good one I did not mark it.....

Comment: Thanks Rohit, this fix the home page slider issue, however all my other pages are still run out of place, could you help to look into it?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Now Add this css in your css as like this #container{clear:both;}

Answer (score 0):

Just change this class and set it again because its slider

```
ul.bjqs {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

I am sure there will be some calculations will be done on bases of resolutions so it will better to put in absolute position and then do other stuffs this will result in to same for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Please modify this

```
<ul class="bjqs" style="height: 380px; width: 100%; display: block;">
```

to

```
<ul class="bjqs" style="height: 380px; width: 100%; display: block; overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to solve this without rewriting your code is:

Go to your `li a` selector (line 73) and remove `height: 28px;`

You `a` tags already get their correct height and setting it manually messes up with the flow of the display.

Comment: Hi Gil, tried this, the whole content area moved slightly to the left, but still out of place and not like in other browsers

Comment: That's weird, in my browser it works. So, after removing this attribute, add `clear: left;` to your `#content` selector.

Comment: Still the same even after adding clear:left; to #content

Comment: Since you're getting different results than me, I suggest using the `inspect element` option (preferably with firebug) on the 'home' menu element and then use you arrow keys to go through the menu and find out which one has the large borders that cause the div to be moved aside.